# Extract a string using gsub between two "-" from dataframe

Tags: r, regex

Please help in gsub code in R for extracting `9045` and `GT200`
 from `DT-9045-BIN1-C-A1, DT-GT200-BIN5-E-A2` 
which are appearing in a data frame.

Data frame has 1000's of entry

Need to extract from each entry

That is extracting between first "-" and second "-"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `gsub`.  Match the pattern of one or more characters that are not a `-` (`[^-]+`) from the start (`^`) of the string followed by a `-` or (`|` a `-` followed by characters (`.*`) and replace it with blank (`""`)

```
gsub("^[^-]+-|-.*", "", str1)
#[1] "9045"  "GT200"
```

---

Or another option is `sub` where we match characters that are not `-` followed by `-`, then capture the characters that are not a `-` as a group (`([^-]+)`) followed by a `-` and other characters, replace it with the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group

```
sub("^[^-]+-([^-]+)-.*", "\\1", str1)
#[1] "9045"  "GT200"
```

---

Or using `str_extract` with regex lookaround to match one or more characters that are not a `-` following a `-`.  The `str_extract` will only extract the first instance to get the expected output

```
str_extract(str1, "(?<=-)[^-]+")
#[1] "9045"  "GT200"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("DT-9045-BIN1-C-A1", "DT-GT200-BIN5-E-A2")
```